# Need help with two lines in a formula on a process builder. How can use a OR and ISCHANGED together?

Tags: formula, process-builder, administration, configuration

I have a picklist with 3 values:
fulltime, halftime, and unemployed.

My process builder updates halftime and unemployed to "fulltime" (expected behavior) whenever we- get a contract and the start date is <= today. The problem is that I need two additional fields on the object, which are time and distance to get updated too even if the status is ALREADY "fulltime".

So far they only get updated if the status is NOT "fulltime", so only when records are being created from halftime or unemployed to fulltime. It doesn't work when we try to update distance and time when the value is already fulltime. How can I get these two fields to get updated even when status is fulltime already?

TLDR: If it's not fulltime, it should be updated to fulltime OR if it's already fulltime, time and distance should get updated whenever their values change.

This is my formula which is not working:

```
AND(
NOT(ISNULL( [App__c].Start_date__c)),
NOT(ISPICKVAL([App__c].Candidate_Status__c, 'fulltime')),
OR(ISCHANGED([App__c].Time__c)), 
OR(ISCHANGED([App__c].Distance__c )),
([App__c].Start_date__c <= TODAY())
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your misunderstanding seems to be in `OR` syntax itself. What you want the actual formula to check is unclear, but the way `OR` works is you pass in a bunch of conditions for it to evaluate, all *inside* the one function call.

```
OR(
    ISCHANGED(Field_1__c),
    ISCHANGED(Field_2__c)
)
```

Structurally, it's the same as what you already do with your `AND` function.

Comment: I see, what I want to do is if status is fulltime, then I want distance and time to get updated. They only get updated when status is changing from halftime or unemployed to fulltime. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @WatsonElementary Don't forget to upvote (when you have enough reputation score) and accept an answer if it solved your problem (or gave you a strong push in the right direction). Accepting an answer gives both you and the person who wrote the answer reputation score, and signals to the community that you don't need further help with this question (and to others with similar problems that this can probably help them too).